# What does Headphone Actor represent or mean?

Tags: kagerou-project

On the 6th episode of Mekakucity Actors, there was a scene where Takane was directed by, presumably, her own voice to escape the city, which was falling apart. Now, there was a similar scenario in the song the episode was based on with the same title in the Kagerou Project, which was what the entire anime is based on.

I'm not sure I understand what the purpose of this is. Because it doesn't seem like it's real. The city she lives in is not literally falling apart, I don't think. Otherwise everyone else would have died. So it must be symbolic for something. Am I missing anything here? What is the purpose of the song and the scene in that particular episode?

Comment: For what it's worth, I expect that this will be explained in at least a _little_ more detail later on in the series.

Comment: Well I thought that the Kagerou Project itself ended and was curious if there's something I missed. Because I didn't get any explanation from the songs themselves. Unless there's more story related stuff from the manga/ln/anime not in the songs.

Comment: The song series is over, yes, but the manga/LNs/anime expand a lot on the songs. (They kind of have to... if the 22 songs were really all there was to the series, you wouldn't have material for 5+ light novels.)

Answer (score 1):

The town falling apart isn't 'symbolic' of anything. The story premise was that since she was brought into the Haze artificially she got looped in with Hibiya and Hiyori's Haze the same way Haruka/Konoha did. Hence the line from the song "Rioting people, a sobbing girl…" which is accompanied by the image of the classic blue and pink spots that normally represent Hibiya and Hiyori.

The town falling apart was the end of the loop she had entered during and because she was artificially stuck into their loop she wasn't going to enter the second loop in the same manner of repetition that Hibiya would. It is stated in the song Kagerou Days "With that, like a cricket’s sound being disturbed, the light blue of summer darkened away…" Hibiya basically just passes out and wakes up with the previous day repeating.

Because Hibiya followed the standards of normally entering the Haze, the loop was customized to him. Takane/Ene would have to go through the day and upon the town falling apart she would wake up the next day in the same situation in the same spot as the day before to continue the loop. The crumbling town was the destruction of that specific loop that would carry into the next loop upon rebuilding the area from the beginning.

The reason that this wasn't repetitively shown is that she exited the Haze before the loop completely ended, and through which she entered the computer and then the story continues into Ene's Cyber Journey (Ene no Dennou Kikou).